# Wordpress - wp_oembed_get() - Breaking Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that uses Genesis and works fine locally on my machine.  I uploaded to test on a server, and the youtube videos (embedded using `wp_oembded_get()`) are not loading, but also, they seem to be trying to load and as result preventing the rest of the page from loading properly.

The dev site can be viewed here:  http://djtprogramming.com/kim_filardi/testimonials/

The code used to display each video is:

```
<div class='youtube'><?php print wp_oembed_get($videos[$count]['video'], array('width'=>200, 'height' => 113));
```

The `$videos` array is populated by the ACF plugin (Advanced Custom Fields)

Te page should look like this: http://pbrd.co/1d5Yl0H, but as you'll, the videos will not appear.

I don't seem to be getting any errors.  And iFrame in which the YouTube videos load, doesn't seem to appear at all